# How to handle phpThumb src prefix?

Tags: php, phpthumb

Because of my folder structure in the framework I use (cake) I am forced to use "../../" as a prefix for the src parameter.

```
<img src="$path_to_phpThumb?src=../../my_image.ext" />
```

How would be recomanded to do in order to get red of "../../" ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alias to redirect requests to the location where your images reside.

i.e. in apache the following would map src="/img/foo.jpg" to the path below

```
Alias /img /var/www/html/app/webroot/images
```

Comment: Yes, I think that could work, but while in the src path I will allways refer the webroot I found yet another workarownd: I have overwritten the $_GET['src'] in the phpThumb.php file, prepending to it that double "up" string.